How to Fix the WhatsApp API Error: Unexpected Key 'url' on Button Parameter?
Error sending WhatsApp message: {"error":{"message":"(#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params","type":"OAuthException","code":132000,"error_data":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","details":"body: number of localizable_params (1) does not match the expected number of params (0)"},"fbtrace_id":"A4Gw-m3NyfCtH5ss-ep81un"}}
const payload = {
  'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
  'to': phoneNumberString,
  'type': 'template',
  'template': {
    'name': 'velvetek_gaming',
    'language': { 'code': 'en' },
    'components': [
      {
        'type': 'header',
        'parameters': [
          {
            'type': 'image',
            'image': {
              'link': 'https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/425192705_2193394084357501_7755989335530972859_n.png?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8b1bef&_nc_ohc=ByZFeTJNrlMQ7kNvgGB_Cp1&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&oh=01_Q5AaIKkP-QjlEe9thFos0I2mPJIJyZWJpoPhR23yvSvTleBH&oe=66DC37EF'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'type': 'body',
        'parameters': [
          {
            'type': 'text',
            'text': 'Are you looking to build a gaming PC or a design setup? Message us now for the best deals'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'type': 'button',
        'sub_type': 'QUICK_REPLY', // Updated to QUICK_REPLY
        'index': '0',
        'parameters': [
          {
            'type': 'text',
            'text': 'Call Us Now'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const response = await axios.post(url, payload, { headers });
console.log('Message sent:', response.data);
return response.data;

to send messages to frontend

Separate your code and error text and explain exactly what it is you want help with.

I think there is the issue in your component
try using format structure like this example to send button template
{
    "name": "temp_btn_3",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "HEADER",
            "format": "TEXT",
            "text": "testing header"
        },
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "welcome"
        },
        {
            "type": "FOOTER",
            "text": "thank you"
        },
        {
            "type": "BUTTONS",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                    "text": "Reply me"
                },
                {
                    "type": "PHONE_NUMBER",
                    "text": "Call Me",
                    "phone_number": "+9179xxxxxxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "language": "en",
    "status": "APPROVED",
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "id": "*********"
}

You can update header for image type and can add multiple buttons too as per your requirement.
